# Why filelib:is_dir and filelib:is_regular functions doesn't work properly with files and folder that contain blank space?

Tags: erlang

I have the directory `C:/Users/David/test`

This directory contains:

```
-test one (folder)
-test.one (folder)
-Nuevo documento de texto.txt (file)
```

```
-module(tut).
-export([main/0]).

main() -> 
 {_, DD} = file:list_dir("C:/Users/David/test"),
 [{H, filelib:is_dir(H)} || H <-DD].
```

When I run the code the two folders give me false. And they should return true.

When I change `is_dir` by `is_regular` and execute the code all three are false too, but `Nuevo documento de texto.txt` is a regular file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the full path for the `filelib:is_dir` to work correctly.

```
[{H,filelib:is_dir("C:/Users/David/test/" ++ H)}|| H <-DD].
```